# On the sum of digits of primes in binary form

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, digits

Let $s_2(m)$ be the sum of digits of $m$ in binary form.

I would like to ask the following question:

> Is it true that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ there is at least one
>   prime $p$ which has $s_2(p)=n$?

After some search I found some papers which study the sum of digits of *all* the primes below $N$ but not an answer to my question.
Any references (or an answer) would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there actually an obvious counterexample to the statement that for any odd prime $p$ there is a $2^k>p$ with $p+2^k$ prime too?

Comment: Erdos showed that there are arithmetical progressions of odd numbers $n$ such that there is no $k$ with $n+2^k$ prime. These arithmetical progressions satisfy the conditions of Dirichlet's Theorem, so there are prime numbers $p$ such that $p+2^k$ is never prime. See, e.g., https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/covertalkunder.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, very interesting! The counterexample at your link is quite big, actually I was unsuccessfully looking for $k$ with $2131+2^k$ prime, I wonder what happens with it...

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number#The_dual_Sierpinski_problem

Comment: @GerryMyerson wow thanks, I would never reach $2^{4583176}$ on my pc :D